# Move comment to previous line in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, refactoring

I have "inherited" some Java code that contains a lot of comments at the end of statements, e.g.:

```
this.apiAccess=apiAccess;// used for reading model
```

SonarCube flags this as a minor rule violation, and states that the comment should appear above the code instead:

```
// used for reading model
this.apiAccess=apiAccess;
```

Is there an easy way to accomplish this in IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can play with search and replace in whole project with regular expressions, for example:

Search:

```
^(.*) (//.*)
```

Replace with:

```
$2\n\r$1
```

this replaces (as an example):

```
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>  // Comment
```

for

```
// Comment
<solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
```

Comment: Thank you!
I fiddled around with it a bit and ended up matching the starting whitespace as well. So for the record: search for
    ^(\s*)([^\s].+)(//.*) and replace with $1$3\n$1$2